# Allow mass asignment in certain contexts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, mass-assignment

I have several Rails models that I'm trying to expose via a REST api.  I'm looking for a simple way to allow mass assignment in certain contexts (through the api or admin interface) but to disallow when populating from user based forms.

There are a few catches as well.  First, I'm populating a bunch of child objects using  `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  Second, I'm using `resource_controller` plugin which automatically applies params correctly for you in standard update case. The api controllers are in their own "namespace" so I'm open to something DRY that could be implemented in a base controller.

Several solutions come to mind but no clean solution presents itself at the moment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mixed solution.
That said, you can tweak ActiveRecord in order to allow mass assignment depending on user role.

You can implement the system yourself or use an existing plugin, such as [safe_mass_assignment](http://github.com/jamis/safe_mass_assignment).

Comment: Never heard of this plugin before.  Thanks for the tip!  I'll just need to tweak resource controller as well so it knows about the option for mass assignment.